# Get the index of an array by position

Tags: javascript

I want to get the index of an array by position. Is this possible? For example, I want the following function to print:

```
var args = new Array();
args["name"] = "john";
args["surname"] = "smith";

printPerson(args);
function printPerson(args) {

    for(var i = 0; i < args.count; i++) {
        ???
    }
}
```

> "name:john surname:smith"

(ie `name` & `surname` should not be hardcoded inside function)

**EDIT**
The order they printed out is not important!

Comment: So you just want to print the key / value pairs in an associative array?

Comment: You're better off using an object for that.

Comment: @Chris yes, that's what I'm trying to tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested:

```
for(var i in args)
   alert(i + ":" + args[i]);
```

**EDIT:**

If order matters, you could make an array of objects.. Like

```
args[0] = { key: 'name', value: 'john' };
args[1] = { key: 'name', value: 'mike' };

for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
  alert(args[i].key + ":" + args[i].value);
```

Or something..

Comment: Note that there is no guaranteed order here, so you may get 'surname' before 'name'.

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning properties to an Array, and want those properties to appear in some order?

No need for an Array. Better use an Object literal:

```
var person = { 
               name:'John', 
               surname:'smith',
               toString: function(){
                          return 'name: '+this.name
                                   +', surname: '+this.surname;
                         }
             };
alert(person); //=>name: john, surname: smith
```

Answer (score 3):

These values are simply properties of the `args` object. So you can iterate over them by using `for...in`

```
var args = new Array();
args["name"] = "john";
args["surname"] = "smith";

for(x in args)
    document.write(x + ":" + args[x] + " ");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var args = new Array();
args["name"] = "john";
args["surname"] = "smith";

function printPerson(args) {

    for(key in args) {
        alert(key + ":" + args[key]); // you can write your values, rather than alert them, but gives you the idea!
    }
}

printPerson(args);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the correct use of `Array` in JavaScript, which should only use a numeric index. By adding string-key properties, you are adding instance properties but they aren't enumerable in a `for` loop. You can use an `Object` instead, which is a set of key/value pairs.

KooiInc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708639/get-the-index-of-an-array-by-position/7708693#7708693) demonstrates the use of `Object` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [for .. in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for this. There's an example on that page.